# What exactly happens if input and output file is the same?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

Let's say that I execute following command:

```
tr a-z A-Z < file > file
```

There are two redirections: `< file` and `> file`. Both are processed before `tr` command and as far as I know, if there are multiple redirections, then they are processed from left to right. In other words first `< file` and then `> file`. Does the `< file` simply mean that if command starts, then `stdin` comes from file named `file`? Then the `> file` part is processed and this means that output is sent to file named `file`. Also file named `file` is truncated to zero size. Now finally the commands(`tr` in my example) starts, but as the input file was truncated to zero in previous step, then it simply processes an empty file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's right. `>` truncates the file before the command is started, so the command sees an empty input file. It doesn't actually matter that the redirections are performed from left to right (except that you'll get an error if the file doesn't exist, whereas `>file <file` would create the file first).

With `somecommand <file >>file`, most of the time, you'll get an infinite loop as the command reads its own input. However, for a short file, it's possible that the command detects the end of the input before it's written out anything, in which case this will behave as if the input and output were separate files.

With `somecommand <file 1<>file`, it's more complicated. Depending on whether the command expands or shrinks the file, it may or may not loop on its own input. If the command always shrinks the file (e.g. `grep` without things like line numbering or coloring), i.e. if byte N of the output always depends only on bytes 0..N-1 of the input, then this behaves as if the two files were different. I don't recommend relying on that though: it's fragile in many ways, and leaves a mess if the command is interrupted in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same file for both input and output is guaranteed to give you problems.  The problem will start as soon as the shell opens both files because the output file will get truncated.

If you append to the output, then it will loop indefinitely until the disk is full or the max file size is reached.